# How to negate the invertibility criterion of a bounded operator

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in B(X,Y)$. $T$ is invertible iff $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold

$ (1)  cl(ImT) = Y $

$ (2) \exists c>0 $ such that $\|x\| \leq c\|Tx\|, \forall x \in X$

This criterion is usually used in negative form, so I need to negate (2). My professor said the negation of (2)is the following:

$(2') \exists \{x_n\} \subseteq X,\|x_n\|=1 $ such that $\|Tx_n\| \to 0$ for $n\to \infty$

I am trying to prove that but I get something else:

$ \sim (\exists c>0 $ such that $\|x\| \leq c\|Tx\|, \forall x \in X) $

$= \forall c>0 \exists x \in X $ such that $\|x\| > c\|Tx\|,  $

$= \forall c>0 \exists x \in X $ such that $1/c > \|Tx\|/\|x\|,  $
$= \forall c>0 \exists x \in X $ such that $1/c > \|Tx\|/\|x\|,  $

$= \forall c>0 \exists x \in X $ such that $1/c > \|Tx\|, \|x\|=1  $

Since the inequality is valid $\forall c>0$, $\|Tx\|=0$ so $Tx=0$, so $x \in KerT$.

Isn't this correct? And how do I get to $(2')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful with the order of the quantifiers on your last line. For every $c$ there is an $x$ (that may depend on $c$) such that $\|Tx\| < 1/c$ while $\|x\| = 1$. You don't have that there is one such $x$ that works for all $c$ so that we can conclude that $Tx=0$.

To get (2') all we need to do is to construct a sequence using your last line. For $c=1$ there is an $x_1$ such that $\|Tx_1\| < 1$. For $c=2$ there is an $x_2$ such that $\|Tx_2\| < 1/2$, etc. Then $\|Tx_n\| \to 0$ but $\|x_n\|=1$.

Comment: If  this proposition  "$ \forall c>0 \exists x \in X $ such that $1/c > \|Tx\|, \|x\|=1  $ "does not state that one such x works for all c, what should the proposition be in order to have that?

Comment: Does  putting the quantifiers in this order ∀c>0 ∃x∈X  always imply that x may depend on c?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO It would have to be "$ \exists x \in X\forall c>0$. The order plays a big role. Yes to your second question. 

"For every real number $x$, there is an integer that is bigger than $x$." is true, but "There is an integer that is bigger than every real number $x$" isn't.

Comment: Assuming the order of the quantifier were "∃x∈X ∀c>0", then would this conclusion hold "1/c > ||Tx|| -->  Tx=0"? Because I feel  that conclusion would be for that particular x, let's say $x_0$ such that $Tx_0=0$and I don't know if any other $x$ exists, so I can't write  $Tx=0$, that implies it is for all x. If I instead had "∀ x∈X ∀c>0" , then I can conclude that $Tx=0$ right?

Comment: If it was $\exists x \in X\forall c>0$ then it would hold that $\|Tx\| =0$ and thus $Tx=0$ **for that $x$**. If you had $\forall x \in X\forall c>0$, the same would hold for all $x$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot